# Proc*C Application Crashing With Oracle 12.2

Tags: c++, debugging, select, gdb, oracle12c

While running some applications on 172.19.112.43 server, oracle is causing applications to crash. **Oracle Version 12.2 , Linux Version - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.0 (Santiago).**

Please find below the crash trace:

```
0  0x00007f332756754b in raise () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0 

1  0x00007f33233eb212 in skgesigOSCrash () from   /home0/ora12c/app/ora12c/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1 

2  0x00007f3323a0b535 in kpeDbgSignalHandler () from /home0/ora12c/app/ora12c/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1 

3  0x00007f33233eb550 in skgesig_sigactionHandler () from /home0/ora12c/app/ora12c/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1 

4  <signal handler called> 

5  0x00007f332144220c in kpudfni () from /home0/ora12c/app/ora12c/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1 

6  0x00007f3321442f9b in kpudfn2 () from /home0/ora12c/app/ora12c/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1 

7  0x00007f33213c5e8a in sqlcucDefine () from /home0/ora12c/app/ora12c/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1 

8  0x00007f3323d225cb in sqlall () from /home0/ora12c/app/ora12c/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1 

9  0x00007f3323d1f5bc in sqlnst () from /home0/ora12c/app/ora12c/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1 

10 0x00007f3323d1b206 in sqlcxt () from /home0/ora12c/app/ora12c/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1 

11 0x00007f3326a88c51 in CSTDbConnection::ProcessSelect (this=0x646900 <objDBConn>, VecColumnsobj=std::vector of length 1, capacity 1 = {...}, VecWheresobj= 
std::vector of length 1, capacity 1 = {...}, strOrderBy="") at    STDbConnException.cpp:11377
```

This is happening across lot of applications. **The same application is running absolutely fine with Oracle 12.1 but while running the applications on Oracle 12.2 it is crashing**. We also disabled the diagnostic features at Client as well as Server side by setting the following parameters in sqlnet.ora file.

DIAG_ADR_ENABLED=OFF

DIAG_SIGHANDLER_ENABLED=FALSE

DIAG_DDE_ENABLED=FALSE

But even this did not help. The piece of code that is throwing this error is :

```
    short nIndex7=0;
    int intVecIndex=0;
    int LastIndex =0;
    while(true)
    {
    memset(szDBErrorCode,'\0',DB_ERROR_LEN);
            vector<CSTColumn> objVecColumns;
            //cout<<"Inside While Loop"<<endl;
            EXEC SQL FETCH select_cursor INTO DESCRIPTOR 'out';
```

The FETCH statement is throwing error for all the applications. Sometime the select query runs multiple times before throwing the error.

The Cpp part of the code throwing the error is

```
        short nIndex7=0;
       int intVecIndex=0;
       int LastIndex =0;
       //EXEC SQL WHENEVER NOT FOUND DO BREAK ;
    while(true)
    {
    memset(szDBErrorCode,'\0',DB_ERROR_LEN);
            vector<CSTColumn> objVecColumns;
            //cout<<"Inside While Loop"<<endl;
            /* EXEC SQL FETCH select_cursor INTO DESCRIPTOR 'out'; */

{
  struct sqlexd sqlstm;
 sqlstm.sqlvsn = 13;
 sqlstm.arrsiz = 4;
 sqlstm.sqladtp = &sqladt;
sqlstm.sqltdsp = &sqltds;
sqlstm.iters = (unsigned int  )1;
sqlstm.offset = (unsigned int  )822;
sqlstm.selerr = (unsigned short)1;
sqlstm.sqlpfmem = (unsigned int  )0;
sqlstm.cud = sqlcud0;
sqlstm.sqlest = (unsigned char  *)&sqlca;
sqlstm.sqlety = (unsigned short)4352;
sqlstm.occurs = (unsigned int  )0;
sqlstm.sqfoff = (         int )0;
sqlstm.sqfmod = (unsigned int )2;
sqlcxt(&my_context, &sqlctx, &sqlstm, &sqlfpn); // This line gave the core
  }
```

Can somebody please shed light on this.

Comment: It doesn't look like you recompiled your app for 12.2: libclntsh.so.12.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bona fide Oracle bug. Fixed in 18.1 but with a Patch for 12.2

Bug 26911212 : PROC APPLICATION CRASH IF SQL ARE SPREAD ACCROSS MULTIPLE FILES

Has exactly the symptoms you - and we - encountered: invalid call to malloc/realloc from somewhere deep in the nether regions of the Pro*C sqlctxt causing sigabrt()

The patch notes describe this as a precompiler bug, which implied it might be a problem in the code generated by the precompiler, which would not match our symptoms (we actually compiled on 12.1 but were running on a 12.2 client). In fact, when you run the patch, it's the shared libraries libclntshcore.so and so on that get patched, so unless you're linking statically it's the execution-time client environment that was broken, not the precompiler environment.